# How to find the previous element of an element found in Appium Xpath?

Tags: selenium, xpath, appium

**PROBLEM:**
I am having an issue to identify an element in Appium.

As I can't identify the element, I managed to identify by xpath the next element. Let's call it "FOUND" element.

SO now I try to get the previous element from this element "FOUND".

**DETAILS:**
[image]

In this screenshot above, you can see the elements I am speaking about.
To find the "FOUND" element, I am looping in all the element with the class "android.widget.TextView", I extract the attribute 'text' and compate it to the string 'Website'.
Then from the element FOUND, I try to find the element I need. I tried so many various expression, but I didn't succeed to get it. I use a "try, except" to try to cath it, but without success.

here is the code:

```
elements_of_profile_detail_page = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("android.widget.TextView")
list_xpath=[
    "preceding-sibling::android.widget.TextView[1]",
    "preceding-sibling::android.widget.TextView[1]",
    "(/preceding-sibling::android.widget.TextView)[1]",
    "/*preceding-sibling::android.widget.TextView[1]",
    "(/*preceding-sibling::android.widget.TextView)[1]",
    "(preceding-sibling::android.widget.TextView)[1]",
    "../android.widget.TextView[0]",
    "preceding-sibling::*[1]",
    "/preceding-sibling::android.widget.TextView",
    "preceding-sibling::android.widget.TextView",
    "(preceding-sibling::android.widget.TextView)[1]"
]
i=0
while i<len(list_xpath):
    try:
        website = element_of_profile_detail_page.find_element_by_xpath(list_xpath[i]).get_attribute('text')
        print(f"website : {website}")
        print(f"xpath : {xpath}")
        break
    except:
        print("It didn't work!")
        i+=1
```

And here is another screenshot with more details of the element I need:

[image]

I am using Appium 1.15.1 and Python 3.7. I don't think it is important as it is a matter of Xpath.

I hope I gave enough details to find the solution. I am working on it since very early this morning.

Comment: Appium Desktop will show the app id, accessibility id (if it contains unique id) and xpath in top right side of selected element. You can select in the left and copy xpath from there

Answer (score -1):

You can directly find the element by using its text in the xpath like:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@text,'AlfangeAcademy')]")
```